# fixed layout in formview template

Tags: asp.net, formview

I have n pages with formviews, all sharing a similar layout inside their item/edit/insert templates.

For example all item and edit templates have a header and body part inside where i put the fields. The header has a certain style and the body part too.

My question is how can i enforce this style in all my formviews without repeating the same bulk css styles all the time.

Now i'm using masterpages for this with multiple formviews on 1 page. 
That's not good i think. I want one 1 page for edit/insert/item and 1 formview.

I would prefer somehow to define the style for edit template once and load it into every formview. Ofcourse not all the formviews have the same fields, so like masterpages i would like to have 'areas' where i can put my fields.

The perfect way i suppose would be to have a formview span a complete masterpage based page including the contentplaceholders inside it's edit/insert/item templates.

Any ideas are more than welcome.

Edit:
I read it's possible in .Net 4 using dynamic data. I'm stuck with 3.5 for the moment.

Comment: How are you defining your styles?  If you are using class names and style sheets, it's really not a hassle.

Comment: It consists of a number of divs defining the layout and css classes defining the look. I suppose if i spend some more time on contstructing smart css classes it could be managable. 

The next problem will be finding the time to work this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a CSSClass for the form view or some other standard container than use child selectors in your CSS.

Comment: Did that. Ended up using a bunch of divs, separated all the styles into css. It's not perfect, but do-able.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Themes(or Style Sheet Themes) and skins for this.
For Example Create a theme Theme1 and a skin file under it with the following content.

```
<asp:FormView  runat="server" 
      RowStyle-BackColor="Blue" />
```

Now you can make pages in your application use the theme by entering the following in web.config.

```
 <pages theme="Theme1">
```

Also you can use RowStyle-CSSClass or  EditRowStyle(to apply to edit template).
You can also enter the style sheet file in the same Theme folder

Comment: Sorry but that's just not flexible enough for me.